# why does free command show more memory usage than other tools

Tags: ram, free

When I use `free -h -l`  command I see 1.8G in use where system monitor app shows me 1.1G in use.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1.8G       1.7G       161M       245M        67M       553M
Low:          853M       735M       117M
High:         1.0G       963M        44M
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.1G       783M
Swap:         3.8G       1.4G       2.4G
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in the first line of `free` the memory is calculated considering (adding) the amount of memory used for caching and buffering.

"System Monitor" shows memory usage without considering the amount of memory cached and buffered.

Check out the line `-/+ buffers/cache:       1.1G       783M` of `free`, this is the same to what "System Monitor" is showing because this line shows the memory usage not considering (deducting) cache and buffers.